# Ubuntu 21.10 headset microphone not working

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I installed Ubuntu 21.10 on my new computer (not a laptop) and everything but the microphone works fine. I can't seem to make it work. It is a jack plug, separated from the audio jack. Everything works fine on my Windows partition.

I have an ASUS ROG Strix z590-e motherboard.

The front panel jacks don't work, but that's no problem for me, I don't mind using the back panel ones.

When I use `pavucontrol` it detects when I plug/unplug the mic. `Alsamixer` does recognise the sound chipset from the motherboard. But when I run the command `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec` it only sees the GC, not the chipset, so I guess this is a clue of what's wrong.

I tried changing the file **"alsa-base.conf"** with the different propositions of adding the

lines 44 options snd-hda-intel position fix=1

and 45 options snd-hda-intel model=aspire-headset-mic (and some variations).

I also used the `hdajackretask`, where this doesn't recognize anything else than the GC audio input (HDMI).

Over the day I've also tried many different things and I can't remember them all.

Sorry if I didn't post enough information, I'm not sure which ones are useful or how to get them.

Thanks for the help !